# Magento 1.9.1: Getting problem in work with layout in module development

Tags: layout, ce-1.9.1.0, module

I am not so familer with magento so i am trying to develop a simple module on magento 1.9.1 with help of this tutorial http://magentotutorial.net/magento-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-module/

but i am facing a problem with display the text in frontend with layout & templates(phtml file)
if i write simple

```
echo "hello";
```

in

```
indexAction() of IndexController.php
```

it display simple hello text on blank screen without any magento template on url sitename.com/hello

[image]

but if write

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

it display my theme layout with any content in content area
[image]

here is my codes
app/code/etc/modules/Dinesh_hello.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dinesh_Hello>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Dinesh_Hello>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Dinesh/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Dinesh_Hello>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Dinesh_Hello>
   </modules>
   <global>
   </global>
   <frontend>
       <routers>
           <dinesh_hello>
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module>Dinesh_Hello</module>
                   <frontName>hello</frontName>
               </args>
           </dinesh_hello>
       </routers>
<layout>
           <updates>
               <hello>
                   <file>hello.xml</file>
               </hello>
           </updates>
       </layout>
   </frontend>
   <global>
 <blocks>
           <hello>
               <class>Dinesh_Hello_Block</class>
           </hello>
       </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Dinesh/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php 
class Dinesh_Hello_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout();
     $this->renderLayout();
        //echo "hello";
    }
}

?>
```

app/code/local/Dinesh/Block/Hello.php

```
<?php
class Dinesh_Hello_Block_Hello extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public function methodblock()
     {
         return ‘informations about my block !!’ ;
     }
}
?>
```

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/hello.xml

```
<layout version=”0.1.0″>
    <hello_index_index>
      <reference name=”root”>
<action method=”setTemplate”><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
      <reference name=”content”>
 <block type=”hello/hello” name=”hello” template=”hello/hello.phtml”/>
      </reference>
   </hello_index_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/hello/hello.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->methodblock();
//echo "hello";
?>
```

Comment: check log for the error?

Comment: please set path hint as yes and check your phtml call or not

Comment: @ND17 i already try this , phtml is not calling

Comment: @QaisarSatti there is no log file at my magento system

Comment: search how to enable error log too

Answer (score 2):

Tested and working follow this..

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Dinesh_Hello>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Dinesh_Hello>
   </modules>

   <frontend>
       <routers>
           <hello>
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module>Dinesh_Hello</module>
                   <frontName>hello</frontName>
               </args>
           </hello>
       </routers>
      <layout>
           <updates>
               <hello>
                   <file>hello.xml</file>
               </hello>
           </updates>
       </layout>
   </frontend>
   <global>
 <blocks>
           <hello>
               <class>Dinesh_Hello_Block</class>
           </hello>
       </blocks> 
   </global>
</config>
```

hello.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version='0.1.0'>
    <hello_index_index>
      <reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
      <reference name="content">
 <block type="hello/hello" name="hello" template="hello/hello.phtml"/>
      </reference>
   </hello_index_index>
</layout>
```

Block/Hello.php

```
<?php
class Dinesh_Hello_Block_Hello extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public function methodblock()
     {
         return 'informations about my block !!' ;
     }
}
?>
```

controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php 
class Dinesh_Hello_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout();
     $this->renderLayout();

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: i apply this changes & also convert other ” ”  to " " in hello.xml but it display only blank page without any message/text

Comment: in phtml write simple echo "hello"; u r getting this or not

Comment: update answer check ti

Comment: @QaisarSatti try this also try echo "hello" in phtml but still showing plane blank page without any template layout

Comment: did you changed the files that i recommended? hello.xml and config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change your `etc/config.xml` to this-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Dinesh_Hello>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Dinesh_Hello>
   </modules>
   <frontend>
       <routers>
           <hello>
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module>Dinesh_Hello</module>
                   <frontName>hello</frontName>
               </args>
           </hello>
       </routers>
       <layout>
           <updates>
               <hello>
                   <file>hello.xml</file>
               </hello>
           </updates>
       </layout>
   </frontend>
   <global>
        <blocks>
           <hello>
               <class>Dinesh_Hello_Block</class>
           </hello>
       </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```